# Fetch Model.ts variables in component class

Tags: angular, typescript

I am new to Angular 6, and I am trying to read the model class variables in component class which will be eventually used in HTML class.
I have tried to use it @Input annotation and use the value under ngOnInit, but declared variable gives undefined error.
But if I try to access value directly in HTML file it works.

My requirement is to have value in component class and pass the variable to HTML class in order to represent in mat-table.

I have tried to look for various forums, but mostly questions are around how to use model values directly in HTML file, but not in component file.

Thanks in advance !!

Comment: Please add a StackBlitz replicating your issue.

Comment: Hi, have you tried using ngAfterInit instead?

Comment: @Simba Meek : Yeah, I have given try with ngAfterInit, its still same :(